# Why doesn't Haskell allow me to be more lax with its function definitions?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I was a bit surprised to find out that

```
head' :: [a] -> b
head' (x:xs) = x
```

raises an

```
Couldn't match expected type `b' with actual type `a'
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for head' :: [a] -> b at type_test.hs:1:10
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for head' :: [a] -> b at type_test.hs:1:10
In the expression: x
In an equation for head': head' (x : xs) = x
```

Why is that? I'd assume Haskell would allow me to be as lax as I want to be, and would find no problem with `[a] -> b`.

Thanks

Comment: One way to read polymorphic type signatures is as logical formulas. The signature `[a] -> b` says “for any `a` and any `b`, given a list of `a`s, I can give you a `b`”, but that’s clearly not true—where would you get a `b` from? Therefore the only thing that function can do is throw an error or loop infinitely. Furthermore, the signature `head :: [a] -> a` makes it clear that `head` must also throw an error, because we can come up with a counterexample for its type—the empty list.

Comment: It is possible GHC will get [partial type signatures](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PartialTypeSignatures) that will allow to write `[a] -> _` (which means, the `_` part will be inferred to be `a`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function type signature is incorrect.  Since the input is of type `[a]`, the output will always be of type `a`.  The type signature `[a] -> b` says that the function will take in any list of things, and return a thing of any (possibly different) type, which is incorrect -- it can only return a thing of the same type `a`.

Comment: It's only incorrect when a != b. But then again, I think the Haskell tradition and spec indicates that all characters map to unique types.

Comment: That's the same as saying that if I have a function that will only return, let's say, oranges, I am prohibited to say it will return... fruits. Or that if it might return X, I can't say it may return anything at all.

Comment: It's incorrect because that type, `[a] -> b` is compatible with a type like `[Int] -> String` while `head` clearly is not.

Comment: @devoured Those phrases are exactly the kinds of things the type system tries to say. It wants to be as general as possible, but no more general. In particular, it seems like you're familiar with type systems that have subtyping so that you could forget, say, an Int into an Any. Haskell does have subtyping, but it is significantly more subtle and designed to keep the types as specific as possible.

Comment: Yeah, the point of the type system is that the function has to be able to work with any valid assignment of types to its type signature.  So type signatures can be more specific than necessary, but not less specific.

Answer (score 4):

When you make a polymorphic function like that, there is an implicit `forall`. You function had type:

```
forall a b. [a] -> b
```

This means it can't just work in one case, but all cases. That means your function must, for example, be able to have this type:

```
[()] -> Float
```

But your function clearly would not be able to have this type.

Answer (score 2):

A function `f` of type `[a] -> b` could be used like this:

```
x :: Integer
x = f ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Clearly `head'` can not be used like that. Therefore `[a] -> b` is not a valid type for `head'`.

The key thing to realize here is that `-> b` does not mean "the function could produce any type `b`, but you do not know which one, so you can only perform operations on it that would work with all types". To express that you'd need existential types. Rather it means "the function can produce any type `b` that the user requests", that is the function can be used as an expression of any possible type `b` and it must then be able to produce a value of that type. Clearly `head'` is not capable of that.

Comment: I think you mean ``head'`` instead of ``max'``

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the type signature per se, nor with the code.
But the point is that your code needs to be a proof of the proposition that is implied in the type signature.

But your code only shows that you can make a value of some type a from a list of values of the **same type** a. Nowhere do you show that you can make a value of any unrelated type. Hence the compiler refuses to accept.

One way to prove the type signature would be:

```
 head xs = error "WTF?"
```

Because this is non-terminating, you can claim that it is any type the caller might want if and when it returns, without lying.